# Hacking concerns

Tags: support

I have noticed that many of my questions on Quora and things from files on my home pc seem to keep popping up on this site, as if someone on here has been watching me and they are not making it a secret with how obvious the questions are.

What can I do about this? luckily my story on my pc files are written in short term so I am not too worried what they find or if they try to rip my story off.

Comment: I dont know why this was given a minus vote, hacking is a serious issue and monitoring peoples activity on other sites is a low move. As long as this doesnt continue I wont need to take further action.

Comment: What keeps "popping up" here?  Or do you mean Quora?

Comment: @JBH, naming/shaming other users with alleged plagiarism is not as effective as reporting them to the moderators.

Comment: @JBH, even assuming you got proof, what can a normal user do with it? There is a spammer around here claiming that their content has been posted without permission here, you just need to click the link they provide to verify the content.

Comment: @JBH, no link here. But a common trick in phishing is to post a seemingly legitimate link to induce unaware users to click on it. Sometimes this link is masked under a "my content has been plagiarized, click here to check what content I am referring to".

Comment: @Terrycameron if you got hacked not trying to be rude but, thats not really something we can help with. im also very confused about "files on my home pc seem to keep popping up on this site" that makes no sense, ive seen no files even on here other than pictures and text, i dont even think you can upload anything else. As for "my questions on Quora" having similar questions to someone else is normal so, i dont know what your talking about there. and its not like quora is a private website, its public.

Answer (score 15):

If you find your available content published here without attribution, flag the post for moderator attention, explaining the situation (click on FLAG at the bottom of the post, then select the last item in the pop up list you see)

[image]

Plagiarism is not tolerated here.

If you instead find content from your personal laptop shared here, please check who has access to it as a first step. We can't monitor it for you, and we have had already cases of content being misposted by not carefully monitored systems.

Comment: plagiarism may be fine from public posts on other sites, although a low move but leaving links to hack people is a whole other issue. I hope those that do that read this as it will really tick me off if it keeps happening.

Answer (score 4):

**Examples please?**

It would be very interesting (to me anyway) if in this question you would link some quora questions of yours and then links to the subsequent WB stack questions that were derived from your questions.

I suppose if you come up with really awesome questions someone who was constitutionally deficient in awesome might copy them to acquire some of that awesome.  I would like to see the questions so awesome that someone wanted to copy them!